# How to delete partial text from SQL table?

Tags: delete-row, sql-delete

A cracker has cracked my SQL database installing the following script into most of the lines:

```
<script src=http://www.example.com/xx.js></script>
```

I need to delete in every line just this script, (not all the text in the lines) I have found the command:

```
DELETE FROM [tevalifeForum].[dbo].[FORUM_MEMBERS]
      WHERE <Search Conditions,,>
GO
```

But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Restore the database from a backup and start over.  You don't know what else the hacker has done.

Comment: Try regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column type is TEXT and you want to delete lines within that TEXT column, here's something similar to what I've done in the past:

```
DECLARE @script VARCHAR(100), @len INT, @i INT

SELECT
    @script = '<script src=http://www.example.com/xx.js></script>',
    @len = LEN(@script)

SELECT @i = MAX(DATALENGTH([col]))
    FROM [tevalifeForum].[dbo].[FORUM_MEMBERS]

UPDATE [tevalifeForum].[dbo].[FORUM_MEMBERS]
    SET [col] =
    LEFT(CAST([col] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CHARINDEX(@script, [col])-1)
    + SUBSTRING(CAST([col] AS VARCHAR(MAX)), CHARINDEX(@script, [col])+ @len, @1)
    WHERE [col] LIKE '%' + @script + '%'
```

Please make sure that you have a valid backup and understand that this can only be 'undone' by restoring from backup.

Comment: Hello,
Since I am not a programmer I am confused, I would appreciate if you could anwer me again and put the exact command I sould write including the line to be deleted.

Comment: What is the column name that has the injected text?